# Why am I getting this specific error message with my VB codes?

Tags: vb.net

I am not that familiar with Visual Basic and I need to run this set of VB codes.

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim Ticket_Cost As Decimal
          Ticket_Cost = 25.0
        Dim Trainup_times() As Integer = {"9,11,13,15"}
        Dim Trainup_tickets() As Integer = {"480,480,480,480"}
        Dim Trainup_money() As Integer = {"0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0"}

        Dim Traindown_times() As Integer = {"10,12,14,16"}
        Dim Traindown_tickets() As Integer = {"480,480,480,640"}
       Dim Traindown_money() As Integer = {"0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0"}
        For count = 0 To 4
            PrintLine(Trainup_times(count), "\t\t\t", Trainup_tickets(count), "\t\t\t", Trainup_money(count))
            PrintLine(Traindown_times(count), "\t\t\t", Traindown_tickets(count), "\t\t\t", Trainup_money(count))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

I am getting the following error when testing the codes online at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_vb_compiler

Error message:

```
/home/main.vb (17,20) : error VBNC30451: 'count' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have all strings there, as in: `{"9,11,13,15"}`. Then, you need  `For count As Integer = 0 To 3`: you have only 4 elements per array, not 5. `Traindown_money()` *will be* an array of single or double, not  integer values. -- The `PrintLine()` syntax is probably wrorg.

Comment: Thanks. Tried what you mentioned but still not working!

Comment: If you made any changes, you need to update your code. You have more problems there. Have you turned the arrays into real arrays? For now, you have a string in there. `Trainup_money()` and `Traindown_money()` should be Single, Double or Decimal? Do you need to write this to a file? Also, do you need this code to compile for VB6 or VB.Net? Pick one.

Comment: It's not VBA but as the message says *you haven't declared `count`. You do that with a `dim` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to declare your `count`variable before using it on the loop. You can do it in the same line where you declare your `For...Next` loop.

Change `For count = 0 To 4` for `For count As Integer = 0 To 4`. This may make the error disappear.

**EDIT:** I have been looking at your code, and there are some mistakes that should be corrected if you want it to function properly.

First of all, you need to change the way you declare your arrays since you are telling that the elements inside of them are `Integer` and using `"`. You need to remove those quotes from all the array declarations, as well as declaring the last one as `decimal`, since the data is not integer nor string:

```
Dim Trainup_times() As Integer = {9,11,13,15}
Dim Trainup_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,480}
Dim Trainup_money() As Decimal = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}

Dim Traindown_times() As Integer = {10,12,14,16}
Dim Traindown_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,640}
Dim Traindown_money() As Decimal = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
```

You also need to rewrite the loop declaration, since you need to declare `count` as I told you before, and also loop only from `0` to `3`, since you arrays have 4 elements, not 5:

```
For count as integer = 0 To 3
```

Finally, if you need your output to be displayed into the same window, I'd recommend using `Console.WriteLine` function to do it.

```
    For count as integer = 0 To 3
            
      console.writeline(Trainup_times(count) & "   " & Trainup_tickets(count) & "   " & Trainup_money(count) )
      console.writeline(Traindown_times(count) & "   " & Traindown_tickets(count) & "   " & Traindown_money(count) )
      console.writeline("-------------------------")
Next
```

`All` together it would look like this:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim Ticket_Cost As Decimal
          Ticket_Cost = 25.0
        Dim Trainup_times() As Integer = {9,11,13,15}
        Dim Trainup_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,480}
        Dim Trainup_money() As Decimal = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}

        Dim Traindown_times() As Integer = {10,12,14,16}
        Dim Traindown_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,640}
        Dim Traindown_money() As Decimal = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
        For count as integer = 0 To 3
        
           console.writeline(Trainup_times(count) & "   " & Trainup_tickets(count) & "   " & Trainup_money(count) )
           console.writeline(Traindown_times(count) & "   " & Traindown_tickets(count) & "   " & Traindown_money(count) )
           console.writeline("-------------------------")
           
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Try this out and let's see if it Works for you! =)

Comment: Tried what you suggested and I get the following error:
"Unhandled Exception:                                                                                                                                                               
System.IO.IOException: Bad file name or number."

Comment: You are trying to print your information in a file using PrintLine, but you are not opening a file or anything. The correct syntax to use PrintLine should be something like this: 
`FileOpen(1, "c:\trash.txt", OpenMode.Output)`  
`PrintLine(1, "This is a test.")` 

You need to tell the PrintLine function where to print the data you want.

Comment: I want the output in the VB window. Should I use Print then instead of PrintLine?

Comment: Thanks for helping out here! I am still getting the error message  "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Bad file name or number." when running your set of codes.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like you have something in the code you are testing that doesn't work. If it Works correctly when you do it from a link but it doesn't when you paste the code on your compiler, there must be something wrong there.

Comment: Tested in another VB compiler and it works fine! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about **older vb versions**, but this code have alot of mistakes according to **new vb.net version**.

#### Mistake 1 (defining array of integers) :

If you put quotes like below, then it would called **array with 1 string**. Not **array of integers**.

```
Dim Trainup_times() As Integer = {"9,11,13,15"} 'Incorrect
```

Just remove quotes like below:

```
Dim Trainup_times() As Integer = {9,11,13,15} 'Correct
```

#### Mistake 2 (Declare `count` as integer) :

Compiler doesn't know what `count` type is.

```
For count = 0 To 4 'Incorrect
```

You should declare count as integer like below:

```
For count As Integer = 0 To 4 'Correct
```

#### Mistake 3 (Use `vbTab` instead of `\t`) :

`\t` is basically Tab space which is used in **C-Like** languages. Not in **vb.net** .
So just replace `, "\t\t\t",` with  `& vbTab &`. And thats it.

### Final code:

There were other minor mistakes as well. But I assume you can learn by seeing this full code below:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim Ticket_Cost As Decimal = 25.0
        Dim Trainup_times() As Integer =   {9,  11, 13, 15}
        Dim Trainup_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,480}
        Dim Trainup_money() As Integer = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
        Dim Traindown_times() As Integer = {10,12,14,16}
        Dim Traindown_tickets() As Integer = {480,480,480,640}
        Dim Traindown_money() As Integer = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
        For count as Integer = 0 To 3
            Console.WriteLine(Trainup_times(count) & vbTab & Trainup_tickets(count) & vbTab & Trainup_money(count))
            Console.WriteLine(Traindown_times(count) & vbTab & Traindown_tickets(count) & vbTab & Trainup_money(count))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

https://onlinegdb.com/r1M6MSrgO

Comment: Thank you for this very elaborate answer! Highly appreciated. When I copy and paste your code in that online VB compiler, it fails with the following error message: "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Bad file name or number." However when I click on the link you gave, it works fine! Any idea about this behavior?

Comment: @user3115933 Its other problem. Its common error when you open a file and try to read. Many resources address this: [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/bad-file-name-or-number#to-correct-this-error), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102003/14919621). If you share your **full code**, we can easily know which line causes issue. And also **Debugger** will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions in the other answers, the immediate problem can also be fixed by turning on type inference.  This can be done in the project settings to activate it for the project as a whole, or it can be done in an individual file by adding `Option Infer On` as a single line to the top of the project file.

With type inference on, you won't need to explicitly declare the type of a local variable in code in a context where the compiler can figure out what the type should be.  `For` loop index variables are one such context: the compiler can figure out that you need to declare `count` and it can infer that the type should be `Integer` from the type of the indices (`0` and `3` are of type `Integer`).